# Как открыть любой файл с помощью os.startfile() с помощью определенного приложения?

Tags: python, windows

```
import os

os.startfile("C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe")
```

Есть ли аргумент в `startfile()`, для указания с помощью чего открыть файл?

Answer (score 2):

Нет, такого аргумента у `os.startfile` нет. Но можно использовать `subprocess.Popen`:

```
import subprocess

prog_path = r"C:\Windows\system32\notepad.exe"
file_path = r"D:\file.exe"

p = subprocess.Popen([prog_path, file_path])
```

Или если уж очень хочется - `os.system`:

```
import os

prog_path = r"C:\Windows\system32\notepad.exe"
file_path = r"D:\file.exe"

os.system(f"{prog_path} {file_path}")
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import winreg

# Путь к расширению файла .txt в реестре
file_extension = '.txt'
reg_path = f'Software\Classes\{file_extension}'

# Создание/открытие ключа расширения файла в реестре
key = winreg.CreateKey(winreg.HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, reg_path)

# Установка значения (путь к исполняемому файлу) в ключе
winreg.SetValue(key, None, winreg.REG_SZ, 'C:\Path\To\Your\TextEditor.exe')

# Закрытие ключа
winreg.CloseKey(key)
```